# invisible pdf text in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

I want to insert invisible text into a pdf generated in iOS. How can this be done?

This is how I am generating PDF at the moment:

```
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath words:(NSString *)string
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

    [self drawText:string];


    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PDF source code, invisible text can be written using *Text Rendering Mode 3* ('Neither fill nor stroke glyph shapes'). That's how OCR inserts its text into PDF pages which basically consist of only a scanned image:

```
3 Tr
```

Other text rendering modes are indicated like this in PDF source code:

- `0 Tr`   (fill text)
- `1 Tr`   (stroke text)
- `2 Tr`   (fill, then stroke text)
- `4 Tr`   (fill text and add to path for clipping)
- `5 Tr`   (stroke text and add to path for clipping)

You'll have to find out on your own how to instruct your PDF generating library to use Text Rendering Mode 3, though.

See also this answer (on Superuser): [**"PDF has an extra blank in all words after running through Ghostscript"**](https://superuser.com/a/285688/40894)

**Note:** this 'invisible' text will still be selectable; users can still copy'n'paste it; screen readers can read it aloud; text extraction tools can extract it; `pdftotext` can convert it to a text file...